# How to include Logger in Rails 4 external model with Rufus Scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rufus-scheduler

I have RoR 4 API. I´m using Logger wherever in my app, in example logger.debug "..." without problems and I don´t need to include the Logger class.

However I have a model that is called from a task scheduler Rufus Scheduler (such as cron). I would like to use the Logger here, however, I got an error. I guess because it´s not included.

Please, find my class:

```
project_root = File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))
Dir.glob(project_root + '/events/*') {|file| require file}

class Secretary

 def self.executeEvents

   logger.debug "Secretary.executeEvents-->Executing events..."

   # and so on...
```

and the error:

```
=== puma startup: 2015-07-10 11:04:34 +0200 ===
{ 70104498803280 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  70104498803280   job:
  70104498803280     Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob "60s" {}
  70104498803280   error:
  70104498803280     70104498803280
  70104498803280     NameError
  70104498803280     undefined local variable or method `logger' for Secretary:Class
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/Projects/yanpy/dev/yanpyapi/app/models/secretary.rb:8:in `executeEvents'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/Projects/yanpy/dev/yanpyapi/config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:224:in `call'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:224:in `do_trigger'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:269:in `block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:272:in `call'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:272:in `block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:258:in `loop'
  70104498803280       /Users/Rober/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:258:in `block in start_work_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your logger first.

```
def self.executeEvents
   logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log", "development.log"))

   logger.debug "Secretary.executeEvents-->Executing events..."

   # and so on...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that you are not inheriting/including any of the Rails classes (like `ActiveRecord::Base`. That doesn't mean you don't have access to the global project variables

```
class MyKlass

   def call
     logger.info 'bla bla'
   end

   def logger
     Rails.logger
   end
end
```

`MyKlass.new.call`

**Update1:**

...btw this will work only if the Rails environment / Application environment is loaded in that class context (like inside Rake or something). If not (e.g. this is a standalone class outside the project) you need to do `def logger; @logger ||= Logger.new('path/to/log'); end`

**Update2:**

Even better is to stick this to a module and reuse this  as a common interface in similar classes that don't explicitly inherit Rails logger method

```
module RailsLoggerInterface
  def logger
    Rails.logger
  end
end

class MyKlass
  include RailsLoggerInterface

  def call
    logger.info 'bla bla'
  end
end

class OtherKlass
  include RailsLoggerInterface

  def initialize(*args)
    logger.debug("You've initialized with #{args}")
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

**Update 3**

now I realized you need this in context of class method, so if you go with the module solution (mentioned in Update 2) you can do

```
class Secretary
  extend RailsLoggerInterface

  def self.executeEvents

   logger.debug "Secretary.executeEvents-->Executing events..."
  end
end
```